# Changing raster source using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, data-source

I am using QGIS 1.8.0.

I have two raster image files that I want to see interchangeably, so I duplicated the first layer that's already been georeferenced properly to ensure that all the location data etc. would be the same for the second image. But, I can't figure out how to change the layer source for the copied layer from the old image to the new one...

Comment: You're really still working with QGIS 1.8? This is a very, very, very old version that was depreciated in 2013 - so this software is out of support for more than 8 years now! If you indeed still work with this version, it would be time to get an up to date installation of the newest version - QGIS 3.22 is being released in a few days, but 3.20 or 3.16 (long term release) are still out there.

Answer (score 5):

One approach

- You can close the QGIS project file in QGIS.
- Make a copy to be sure to not destroy your work when following my instruction
- Open in a notepad (like Notepad ++ on Windows) the `qgs` file
- search and replace the file name with the one you want to replace
- save
- reopen the project in QGIS

Done

PS: mainly useful because mention of a very old version of QGIS. Otherwise @babel answer is more user friendly!

Comment: Until now 1.8.0 has done everything I want (and that's a lot of things I'm involved in), so "if it t'aint broke don't fix it"! I know that if I change versions, there will be 100+ maps that will need fixing up... Anyway, sadly Thomas's method doesn't seem to load the new file. I'll keep trying tomorrow, because it really should, reading the code.

Comment: Got it! The new file needs a .tfw file associated with it, same as the original file. Works fine now. Many thanks, ThomasG77

Answer (score 1):

Go to Layer properties (right click layer) and select source tab. At the bottom, you find Layer source where you can select a new file by clicking the three `dots`.

[image]

Comment: Fine too. My own answer was because I was not sure how it works in QGIS 1.8.0. Do not remember what the UI looks like in this old version ;)

Comment: Oh my gosh: the question is indeen on QGIS 1.8 ! A typo (3.8? 3.18?) or indeed OP is still using 1.8 - out of use since 2013?